# DAX EARLIER() function in Power Query

Tags: dax, powerquery, m

Is there an an equivalent to EARLIER in M/Power Query?

Say, I have a table with lots of different dates in column DATE and a smaller number of letters in column LETTER. I now want the maximum date for each letter.

In DAX, I would use something like CALCULATE(MAX([Date]),FILTER(ALL(Table),[Letter]=EARLIER([Letter])).

How would I achieve the same in M?

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I see, they require a lot more technical insight than I had hoped... I'll try to test them both and mark as solved.

Answer (score 0):

2 Solutions in the code below. Notice that each uses "PreviousStep" as basis, so these are separate solutions.

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    PreviousStep = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Date", type date}, {"Letter", type text}}),

    // 1. Add a column to the original table with the MaxDate for each letter
    //    "earlier"  is just the name of a function parameter; it could as well have been "x" or "MarcelBeug"
    AddedMaxDate = Table.AddColumn(PreviousStep, "MaxDate", (earlier) => List.Max(Table.SelectRows(PreviousStep, each [Letter] = earlier[Letter])[Date])),

    // 2. Group by letter and get the MaxDate for each letter
    GroupedOnLetter = Table.Group(PreviousStep, {"Letter"}, {{"MaxDate", each List.Max([Date]), type date}})
in
    GroupedOnLetter
```

Answer (score 0):

In short, there is no exact match for this function. Still, you can use other ways that can produce same results.

To reproduce example offered by [Microsoft in help for `EARLIER` function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee634551.aspx), you can use following code (table1 equals table given in the example before ranking):

```
let
    Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("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", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [ProductSubcategoryKey = _t, EnglishProductSubcategoryName = _t, TotalSubcategorySales = _t]),
    table1 = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"ProductSubcategoryKey", Int64.Type}, {"EnglishProductSubcategoryName", type text}, {"TotalSubcategorySales", Currency.Type}}, "en-US"),
    AddCount = Table.AddColumn(
              table1, 
              "SubcategoryRanking", //(a) is a parameter for function, which equals current record, and function should return value for new cell of "SubcategoryRanking"
              (a)=> Table.RowCount( 
                        Table.SelectRows( 
                        table1, //(b) equals whole table1. This function returns table filtered by given criteria
                        (b) =>  b[TotalSubcategorySales] < a[TotalSubcategorySales]) 
                    ) + 1,
              Int64.Type)
in
    AddCount
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the GroupBy function to group the data by **Letter** and find the Max of the **date** column. So your code should look like.

```
= Table.Group(#"Previous step", {"Letter"}, {{"Max Date", each List.Max([Date]), type date}})
```